# Uploading multiple images PHP

Tags: php, html, image

I am trying to upload multiple images and image descriptions and can't seem to figure out why it is not working properly.

I have a form and within that form there is a table that looks like this:

```
<div id="section_photos">
    <fieldset>
        <table id="photo_table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Roof Section Photo</th>
                    <th>Photo Description</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="photo_tb">
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="file" id="roof_section_photo" name="roof_section_photo[]" /></td>
                    <td><input id="section_photo_desc" type="text" name="section_photo_desc[]"/></td> 
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="button" value="Add Photo" id="newSectionPhoto" />
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

The button here will just add another row to the table that is identical to the `<tr>` in the `<tbody>` allowing the user to add muliple images with descriptions.

When the user clicks on my forms submit button it will try to iterate through each photo and upload the image to a image directory within my website, and insert the directory path, and description information to a MySQL DB.

```
$sectionPhoto = "../images/". $selectedAssocAccount ."/" . $facilityID . "/"
                . basename($_FILES["roof_section_photo"]["name"]); 

foreach($_FILES['roof_section_photo']['name'] as $index => $image){
    $sectionPhotoDesc = $_POST['section_photo_desc'][$index];

    if($_FILES['roof_section_photo']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $status_msg = '';
        $from = $_FILES["roof_section_photo"]["tmp_name"];
        $saved = save_section_photo($from, $sectionPhoto, $status_msg);

        $sectionPhotoQuery = "INSERT INTO table(facility_section_information_id, photo, photo_desc) "
                . "VALUES ('$facilitySectionID', '$image', '$sectionPhotoDesc')";

        //using this to test my query before I submit anything
        echo $sectionPhotoQuery; 
        echo "</br>";

        //mysqli_query($dbc, $sectionPhotoQuery)or die(mysqli_error($dbc));

    } else{
        //THIS IS WHERE I KEEP HITTING..
        echo "Error uploading photo. " . $_FILES['roof_section_photo']['error'];  
    }
}
```

**Output:** *Error uploading photo. Array*

Let's say I have 3 images, I will get my error message 3 times, so I know at least each image is being put into an array and it is being iterated through.

*(I dont think I need to post my `save_section_photo()` function because it's not even getting that far.)*

I am using this exact same process to upload just a single image elsewhere without any issue, but it seems to be giving me problems when I try to use it this way.

I am stumped as to why I keep breaking off on my `if` statement, the images I am using are all small sized, .jpg's that I have also used elsewhere for testing.

Any ideas?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I have included `var_dump( $_FILES['roof_section_photo'] );` before my `foreach` loop.

**Output**

```
array(5) { ["name"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(12) "einstein.jpg" [1]=> string(10) "monkey.jpg" } ["type"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" [1]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(14) "/tmp/php89CrOW" [1]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpPGz7Z9" } ["error"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(0) [1]=> int(0) } ["size"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(4798) [1]=> int(3254) } }
```

Comment: Does your form contain a POST method and a valid enctype? It's not shown in your question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, I have `enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"` within my form tag.

Comment: Have you looked to see if the files are actually being uploaded successfully? Is the directory they are being uploaded to allowed to be written to by the web server user? Are the file sizes within the php.ini settings (or out of bounds for any other reason)? Maybe change your error line to be `echo "Error uploading photo. " . $_FILES['roof_section_photo']['error'];` so you can see what it is actually the error.

Comment: @BA_Webimax They are not being uploaded at all. Yep the directory is allowed to be written to by the web server user. I have changed my error message and included my output in my answer.

Comment: You should `var_dump($_FILES)` to see what you are returning. I expect that `$_FILES['roof_section_photo']['error']` is an array and that you need to be incrementing a counter before the `if`. Something like `$_FILES['roof_section_photo']['error'][$i]`

Comment: @BigRabbit Well that explains why you get where you are getting to. The `Array` will never match `0`. I think you should `var_dump( $_FILES['roof_section_photo'] );` before your `foreach()` and let us see that output.

Comment: @BA_Webimax and @mseifert I added in `var_dump()` and have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think this will work for you...

```
foreach($_FILES['roof_section_photo']['name'] as $index => $image){
    $sectionPhotoDesc = $_POST['section_photo_desc'][$index];

    if($_FILES['roof_section_photo']['error'][$index] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $status_msg = '';
        $from = $_FILES["roof_section_photo"]["tmp_name"][$index];
        $saved = save_section_photo($from, $sectionPhoto, $status_msg);

        $sectionPhotoQuery = "INSERT INTO table(facility_section_information_id, photo, photo_desc) "
                . "VALUES ('$facilitySectionID', '$image', '$sectionPhotoDesc')";

        //using this to test my query before I submit anything
        echo $sectionPhotoQuery;
        echo "</br>";

        //mysqli_query($dbc, $sectionPhotoQuery)or die(mysqli_error($dbc));

    } else{
        //THIS IS WHERE I KEEP HITTING..
        echo "Error uploading photo. " . $_FILES['roof_section_photo']['error'][$index];
    }
}
```

Since you are looping on the `$_FILES['roof_section_photo']['name']` array that stands apart from the `$_FILES['roof_section_photo']` array which is an array of 5 arrays with two elements each. You need to make sure you are using the correct index for them.

Comment: Should I be looping on `$_FILES['roof_section_photo']` instead, or is what I am doing ok?    ..I am going to test this now, thanks

Comment: Optionally, you could create an index with your HTML/JS by making the field this way `<input type="file" class="roof_section_photo" name="roof_section_photo[0]" />` (where it increments them according to how many you have). Then you could loop on the `$_FILES['roof_section_photo']` instead. You would likely need to make that `id` a `class` so you can count and index them with jQuery or your framework of choice. BTW, multiple instances of the same `id` on a page is bad practice and can cause issues with JS.

Comment: Hmm ok I think I understand. Yeah I am aware of duplication of `id`'s being bad, that is my next task to tackle. Thanks for all the help, really appreciate it!